# Add Netflix servers on proxy exception list

Tags: networking

Based on the conversation [here](https://community.sophos.com/products/unified-threat-management/f/web-protection-web-filtering-application-visibility-control/46191/exception-rule-for-netflix-streaming) these urls need to be on exception list

```
^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?nflximg\.com\.?/ 
^https?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?nflxvideo\.net\.?/ 
^https?://[\d+(\.\d+){3}/]*/[0-9]{8}\.ism 
^https?://[\d+(\.\d+){3}/]*/[0-9]{9}\.ism 
^https?://[\d+(\.\d+){3}/]*/[0-9]{10}\.ism 
^http?://([A-Za-z0-9.-]*\.)?netflix-*.vo.llnwd.net/.*[/QUOTE] 
^http?://23.7.139.* 
^https?://secure\.netflix\.com/* 
^https?://uiboot\.netflix\.com/*
```

Is there a way to add these on EOS?

Answer (score 1):

In control panel Network settings you have a Proxy section and an exception tab for adding servers. Not really sure if it supports regular expressions, though.
[image] (sorry the Spanish screenshot version)

Comment: Of course, also accessible through dconf edit, in "system -> proxy" path

Comment: Anyone from the devs know if regex works? I got those added already but netflix still detects proxy.